# How to achieve recursive call - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a custom created dialog module. 
I am passing a `mvc view` called `Cart` to this module.
The `cart view` has a link called `'Create New Contat'` clicking on which the `view(Cart)` will be replaced with another `view(Contact`) using an ajax call. The `contact view` has a button called `cancel`. When the user clicks on Cancel the old `view(Cart)` will replace the existing `view(contact`). 
The problem I am facing is after replacing the view none of the links or buttons work on the view. 
Can some body pls directed me towards a better way of doing this.

Pasted below is the code.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.ddlCart li', function(e) {


            var ddlselectedVal = $(this).attr('id');
            var selectedListinsCount = selected_Listings.length;
            var SelectedMlsnums = selected_Listings.join();
            var agentId = $("#AgentId").val();

            var Action;

            var EnvironmentURL = $("#EnvironmentURL").val();


            var postData = { AgentId: agentId, Mlsnums: SelectedMlsnums, ActionTypeValue: “PreAddToCart” };

            var close = function (event, ui) {
                 $('#dvModalDialog').dialog("close");
                          }
            var open = function (event, ui) {    

                var url = EnvironmentURL + "MLSReports/Stats/SearchContacts";


                $("#btncart_cancel").on("click", function () {
                    $('#dvModalDialog').dialog("close");
                });

                $("#btncart_submit").on("click", function () {

                    var url = EnvironmentURL + "MLSReports/Stats/Cart";

                    //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   
                    $.post(url, {
                        AgentId: agentId, Mlsnums: SelectedMlsnums, ActionTypeValue: "AddToCart"
                    },
                        function (data) {
                            // Replace current data with data from the ajax call to the div.         
                            $("#dvModalDialog").empty().append(data);
                        });                 

                });

                $("#lnkCreateNewcart").on("click", function () {

                    var url = EnvironmentURL + "MLSReports/Stats/Cart";
                    //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   
                    $.post(url, {
                        ActionTypeValue: "preAddorEditContact"
                    },
                        function (data) {
                            //debugger;
                            // Replace current data with data from the ajax call to the div.         
                            $("#dvModalDialog").empty().append(data);


                            $("#btnCancelContact").on("click", function () {
                                  ////********** replace the view (Contact) with the view (Cart).
// In the cancel event I am loading the previous page.I am having problem here. after post none of the controls work.  

                                $.post(url, {
                                ActionTypeValue: "PreAddToCart"
                                   },
                            function (data) {
                                //debugger;
                                // Replace current data with data from the ajax call to the div.         
                                $("#dvModalDialog").empty().append(data);
                            })
                              }); 
                       });
                });

                };
                if (ddlselectedVal == "AddtoCart") {
                    var rd = Mod.ReportsDialog({ title: 'Add To Cart', close: close, open: open });
                    rd.url = EnvironmentURL + "/MLSReports/Stats/Cart";
                    rd.targetElement = '#dvModalDialog'// '#dvSendEmail'
                    rd.formName = '#frmCart'
                    rd.postData = postData
                    rd.open();
                }

            });
```

Comment: Put that code in a separate js file...include it in your Master page and it's done :)

Comment: Which part of the code should I put in a separate js file?

Comment: All of it....in that way it should works on every view